# Java comparing Scanner Input with ENUM

Tags: java, string, enums, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get input validation by comparing the result of a string (from Scanner) to an Enum of potential values.

The Enum contains the name of all Countries in the world, the user is asked to enter a country name -- the input should only be allowed IF the input value is present in the Enum -- is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to try to get Enum by name and catch the exception, using [Enum.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
try {
    CountryEnum country = CountryEnum.valueOf( "user-input" );
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    System.err.println( "No such country" );
}
```

Another way without catching exceptions is to compare user input to each of enum values:

```
String userInput = ...;
boolean countryExists = false;
for( CountryEnum country : CountryEnum.values() ) {
    if( userInput.equalsIgnoreCase( country.name() ) ) {
        countryExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( !countryExists ) {
    System.err.println( "No such country" );
    // exit program here or throw some exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enum.valueOf("string") != null` if the string value exists as a type enum

Find more reference here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/enum_valueof.htm

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: valueOf throws an exception.  It does not return null.

Answer (score 1):

You can equip the Enum with a method `getByName(String name)` that returns `null` if the Enum holds no corresponding value for the given name:

```
public enum Country {

    AFGHANISTAN,
    ALBANIA,
    ALGERIA,
    ...

    public static Country getByName(String name) {

        try {
            return valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when a user enters 'Neverland', obviously `getByName('Neverland')` returns `null`, which you can test for. Instead of `null` you could also include a catch-all value in your list and return that, e.g. `TERRAINCOGNITA`.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
public class EnumTest {
    enum Country{IND, AUS, USA;
        static boolean exists(String key) {
            Country[] countryArr = values();

            boolean found = false;
            for(Country country : countryArr) {
                if(country.toString().equals(key)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return found;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Country.exists(scan.nextLine()));
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Of course you can implement a more efficient search by using a Set to store values.
Enum.valueOf can not be used as it throws following exception when passed value does not match to any enum constant.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
```

Comment: If I use Enum.valueOf with a switch case, would it handle that exception?
Switch (enumVariable)
     case IND:
          code
     default:
          "That is not a valid entry, please reenter";

Comment: Exceptions can only be handled by try/catch or throws clause in Java, switch will do nothing to prevent an exception.


**** Edit***
before passing the argument to switch with Enum case argument input will have to be converted to Enum constant, at which point you'll have to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public enum RegisterType {GUIDE, VISITOR, TICKET, RECEPTIONIEST;}

RegisterType type = RegisterType.valueOf(input.next());
```

Comment: Please make you answer more detailed. I could guess, that input is a Scanner, but it is not evident. A little explanation also would be nice. And there's a question of how to understand that input.next() doesn't contain enum constant.